# Why would using string.Format() break my sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce, string-formatting, string.format

This works:

```
dynSQL = "SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE vendor_item = '" + VendorItem + "' ";
```

...but this doesn't:

```
dynSQL = string.Format("SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE vendor_item = {0}", VendorItem);
```

The latter causes "Cannot find table 0"

This is another example of an attempt to pretty up the code knocking me right out of the saddle and onto the hardpan.

Is encasing the where clause arg in double quotes bookmarked by outer single quotes really the way to go? There has to be a better way (better than my "better way" (which is great except for the fact that it doesn't work)).

Comment: Your second example doesn't include single quotes around the {0}. Intentional?

Comment: I wouldn't think they'd be needed; if they are, that was the problem.

Comment: Why wouldn't you think they would be needed? Why don't you post the SQL that is created from the string? Show us what `dynSQL` looks like in the second case instead of just giving the error message, and we'll see if it makes sense, eh?

Comment: @ErikE: I guess I was expecting that because string.Format() normally "just works," IOW, you don't have to tell it: this is a string, this is an int, etc. It's smart enough to make those conversions for you. I see I was wrong.

Comment: `string.Format` does the job just fine, converting to a string. The thing is, it knows nothing about SQL and the need to wrap the resulting string in single quotes. Why would it do that? You would get strange output if it did this every time. Imagine `string.Format("The number you chose was {0}.", "9")`--would you expect `The number you chose was '9'.` as the result?

Comment: There should be something in C# like Delphi's QuotedStr() for this.

Comment: There is a wrinkle to this, though: when using string.Format() on SQL statements and replacing elements with a table or column name rather than a column value, the single quotes are obviated, a la:

string tblQuery = string.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {0}", tableName); // "tableName" is a string passed to the method containing this code

Comment: And so, you can end up with pieces of string like this:

FROM {0} WHERE upc_code = '{1}'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a better way. Whatever language you're using (you didn't specify--the `string.Format` part) undoubtedly supports parameterized SQL execution. Stop concatenating, and instead use parameters.

For example, [in C# Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738684.aspx) you would do something like this:

```
string esqlQuery = @"SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE vendor_item = @vendoritem";

using (EntityCommand cmd = new EntityCommand(esqlQuery, conn)) {
   EntityParameter vendoritem = new EntityParameter();
   vendoritem.ParameterName = "vendoritem";
   vendoritem.Value = VendorItem;

   cmd.Parameters.Add(vendoritem);
   // go on to execute it as shown in the above link
}
```

By creating a command and executing it, everything is done for you: parameter placement and formatting, including wrapping strings in single quotes and escaping single quotes or using "NULL" for null instead of "'NULL'".

One additional note is that your second code snippet has no single quotes around the token. But even if you get it "working", you're still susceptible to SQL injection. Best practice is to use parameterized SQL instead.